# For what $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ does $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^{\alpha})} dx$ converge

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

For what $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ does the following integral converge:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^{\alpha})} dx$$

Attempt at solution:
We begin by splitting the integral:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^{\alpha})} dx=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^{\alpha})} dx+ \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^{\alpha})} dx$$
We begin by considering the integral on $[0,1]$. Using the theorem on $p-$integrals, we know that:
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^p}dx \hspace{2mm} \text{converges if} \hspace{2mm} p<1$$
Thus,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^{\alpha})} dx=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+x^{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}}} dx \hspace{2mm}\text{ought to converge for} \hspace{2mm}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^\alpha)}<\frac{1}{x} \iff \alpha >\frac{1}{2}$$
However, for $p-$integrals from $[1,\infty]$,
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^p}dx \hspace{2mm} \text{converges if} \hspace{2mm} p>1$$This just means that the previous inequality becomes reversed, and that $\alpha <\frac1{2}{}.$ Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Concerning the integral $\int\limits_0^1$ you get convergence for any $\alpha. $ For $\alpha> 0$ the function behaves at $0$ like $x^{-1/2}.$ For $\alpha>0$ it behaves like $0.$ For $\int\limits_1^\infty$ the function behaves at $\infty$ like $x^{-1/2-\alpha}.$ So $\alpha>1/2$ gives the convergence.